# Comparison among dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Starting from a gff annotation file and an excel with the position of some SNPs, I created two dictionaries:

First one,  the output is like this SNPs_pos[chrx]=[list of SNP positions on chrx]

```
SNPs_pos={}

for line in open (file,"r"):
        col=line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        chrom=col[0]
        posiz=col[1]
        types=col[2]
        delta=abs(float(col[9]))
        if delta>=0.25:
            if types=="snp":
                if chrom in SNPs_pos:
                    SNPs_pos[chrom].append(posiz)
                else:  
                    SNPs_pos[chrom]=[posiz]
```

Second one, the output is like this dic_genes[chrx]=[list of start, stop, ID of the genes on chrx]

```
dic_geni={}

for line in open (annotation, "r"):
    if line.startswith("#"):
        pass
    else:
        col=line.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        chro=col[0]
        start=int(col[3])
        stop=int(col[4])
        ID=col[-1].split(";")[0].split("=")[1]

        if "CDS" in line:
                if chro in dic_geni:
                    dic_geni[chro].append(start)
                    dic_geni[chro].append(stop)
                    dic_geni[chro].append(ID)
                else:  
                    dic_geni[chro]=[start, stop, ID]
```

I want to compare the two dictionaries to select only SNPs in a genes.

I tried something very noob that I'm even ashamed to share:

```
stri=""

for ch in SNPs_pos:
    if dic_geni[ch][start] < SNPs_posi[ch][posiz] < dic_geni[ch][stop]:
        stuff=("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}/n".format(dic_geni[ch], dic_geni[ID], dic_geni[start], dic_geni[stop], SNPs_posi[posiz]))
        stri+=stuff
        
print((stri)[:1000])
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. If you would like a nudge gettign started, I would look to create a new "snp" dictionary by reshaping the current one so you end up with a key of "chromosome" with a value as a list of "posit".

Comment: I have a potential solution, but I can't know if it works if you don't share example input data and expected results. You posted a comment with some code but deleted it. Please add that code to your initial post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @JonSG at least reversing the dictionaries I managed to print some output...